# What is the ideal way to find out the required headers for a route on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, rest

I am working on the client side of an application. The server side is a REST api running on Laravel 5.x.

Calling one of the endpoint I  get a `403 Forbidden`

What is the ideal way to find out the required headers for a route on Laravel?

Comment: documentation???

Comment: It is actually issue for backend developer, it's better to contact him and show error stack trace